# How to display django column filed and help_text horizontal?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I wrote my model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
import datetime

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="no-title")
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="blog",help_text="comma separated")
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=300,default="summary",help_text="Article short introduction")
    cover = models.ImageField("cover img",upload_to="blog/")
    last_activity = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now,auto_now=True)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="no-keyword",help_text="comma separated")
    content = RichTextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class PostAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    fields = ('title','tags')
    class Meta:
        model = Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostAdminForm

    readonly_fields = ('last_activity',)

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

and my model displayed in admin page like this:
[image]

You can see the `Tags` column input text and the `help_text` string wew displayed vertically, this is not what I want, I want to display the `Tags` column input text and the `help_text` property horizontally.

Comment: does the answer I provide work for you? If so, please rate it. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Tags needs to be a relation and not a char field.

You can try using a third party tagging implementation for django (for example, https://github.com/alex/django-taggit)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, but currently I don't want to bring in a new django app, I think there is a way to display the field and the help_text horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

1) in your app directory, create the following folder structure and create a new html file named **change_form.html** (the name is very important for override the default file)

```
your_project
     |-- your_project/
     |-- myapp/
     |-- templates/
          |-- admin/
              |-- myapp/
                |-- change_form.html  <- do not misspell this
```

This structure is recommended by the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)

2) inside the change_form.html, write this

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block field_sets %}
{% for fieldset in adminform %}
<fieldset class="module aligned {{ fieldset.classes }}">
    {% if fieldset.name %}<h2>{{ fieldset.name }}</h2>{% endif %}
    {% if fieldset.description %}
        <div class="description">{{ fieldset.description|safe }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    {% for line in fieldset %}
        <div class="form-row{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' and line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if not line.has_visible_field %} hidden{% endif %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
            {% if line.fields|length_is:'1' %}{{ line.errors }}{% endif %}
            {% for field in line %}
                <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
                    {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
                    {% if field.is_checkbox %}
                        {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ field.label_tag }}
                        {% if field.is_readonly %}
                            <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ field.field }} {{ field.field.help_text|safe }}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
{#                    {% if field.field.help_text %}#}
{#                        <p class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>#}
{#                    {% endif %}#}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This seems like a lot of code, but 99% of it are copied from django's admin template, the only part you need to pay attention is here:

```
{#                    {% if field.field.help_text %}#}
{#                        <p class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>#}
{#                    {% endif %}#}
```

I commented out this portion, this is the section that moved your help text to the next line. I added **{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}** to the end of this line:

```
 {{ field.field }} {{ field.field.help_text|safe }}
```

So that the help text will appear on the same line as your input box.

3) here is my settings.py to reference the templates dir:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+'/templates/'], # <- note I added BASE_DIR+'/templates/'
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

4) Done! I tested this in Django 1.8, so my settings.py may look different from yours

---

I am going to summarize how to override the admin site's template in general:

1) find the django admin template files on your hard drive and find the template that you need to change. For me, I use virtual env on my machine, and this is where I found the template files:

```
/Users/cheng/.virtualenvs/edge/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin
```

The path before the **/lib/** part will be different on your machine.

2) find the template file you want to change and remember the name of the HTML file.

3) open up the HTML file and find the {% block %} you want to override. For this particular question, the HTML file is **change_form.html** and the block name is **{% block field_sets %}**

4) create an HTML file with the same name identified in step 2 and put it in your project's template dir.

5) extends the original HTML and modify the {% block %} as shown above.